# Magento2 : How to add something in my css / less file?

Tags: magento2, bundle

I have a question about something I do not understand what comes from this topic:
[hide-the-qty-box-in-bundle-product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245361/hide-the-qty-box-in-bundle-product)

I want to apply Method 1, which is very simple, but I totally do not understand. In which file, in which location, I can add the indicated piece of text.

And what do I have to do to make this work? (is that what is stated in "note", I understand that piece :))

Thank you for helping.

**edit:**

For more clarity:
If you make a bundle product, you will see quantity boxes on the front page. This is totally unnecessary and I would like to hide.

I have found the right file: _custom.less
I found it in

> app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/web/css/_custom.less

in _custom.less i put the code:

```
.bundle-options-container .nested .field.qty:last-child
{
    display : none;
}
```

The file has correct file permissions (777 to be sure)

With Putty I gave the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

In my browser I have emptied the cache.  Unfortunately no result.

Comment: Do you ever develop a Magento module or design ?

Comment: Have a look at this reply, it is very similar to what you are looking for: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108690/30971

Comment: @Vinz No, I have not done that before.
NicolaLepetit Tnx for your url.

Meanwhile, I have invented that it is:
/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/web/css/_custom.less

I have placed: 'code' .bundle-options-container .nested .field.qty: last-child
{
     display: none;
}

and: 'code' php bin / magento setup: static-content: deploy -f
and the cache emptied.

Unfortunately no visible result.

Comment: Ok.
Do you use a custom theme or the magento native ?

Comment: @Vinz i use the template Infortis Ultimo.

Comment: @TonGeurts: as a general rule, it is not a good idea to work directly on the theme code, because when the theme is updated, you'll lose all your changes. Before changing the .less file, you should verify that the changes in the CSS is actually working in the page. To do that, you can use the developer tools of the browser (I use Firefox or Chorme). Go on the webpage, press F12 and then Style Editor. You should be able to alter the various styles of the page and see the actual results directly on the page. When you have found the correct edit, you can copy the new styles in the CSS or LESS file

Comment: you have to clear view_preprocessed before buid the static-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one of the cleanest way to do it is to create a theme with Infortis Ultimo as parent.

Create a theme.xml in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/default`
Contains :

```
<theme xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance” xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=”../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Config/etc/theme.xsd”>
    <title>Vendor Theme</title>
    <parent>Infortis/ultimo</parent>
</theme>
```

Create a registration.php in the same folder.
Contains :

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/Vendor/default', __DIR__);
```

Now in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/web/css` you can create your `_custom.less` file and add your code :

```
.bundle-options-container .nested .field.qty:last-child
{
    display : none;
}
```

Now launch commands :

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Don't forget to set your new theme on your store.

Answer (score 0):

You have no idea how happy I am with your help!

I get the following message

```
php bin / magento setup: static-content: deploy -f

Deploy using quick strategy

In ErrorHandler.php line 61:

   Warning: DOMDocument :: loadXML (): AttValue: "or" expected in Entity, line:
    1 in /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/fra
   mework / Config / Theme.php on line 76
```

On the first line is:

```
<theme xmlns: xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi: noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "../../../../ lib / internal / Magento / Framework / Config / etc / theme.xsd ">
```

The path might be?:

**Edit 14:54 uur:** Have I tried, that's not it :)

```
/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/etc/theme.xds
```

And, if I go to /admin to log in, I get this to be done instead of the usual login screen:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): AttValue: &quot; or ' expected in Entity, line: 1 in /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Theme.php on line 76

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): AttValue: &quot; or ' expected in Entity, line: 1 in /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Theme.php on line 76
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'DOMDocument::lo...', '/home/u36619p31...', 76, Array)
#1 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Theme.php(76): DOMDocument->loadXML('<theme xmlns:xs...')
#2 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Theme.php(46): Magento\Framework\Config\Theme->_extractData('<theme xmlns:xs...')
#3 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(116): Magento\Framework\Config\Theme->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\UrnResolver), '<theme xmlns:xs...')
#4 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#6 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Config/ThemeFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\\Magento\\Framew...', Array)
#7 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Theme/ThemeList.php(307): Magento\Framework\Config\ThemeFactory->create(Array)
#8 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Theme/ThemeList.php(232): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemeList->_getConfigModel(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemePackage))
#9 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Theme/ThemeList.php(200): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemeList->_prepareConfigurationData(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemePackage))
#10 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Theme/ThemeList.php(161): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemeList->_loadFromFilesystem(Array)
#11 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(689): Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemeList->loadData(false, false)
#12 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(832): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->load()
#13 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme/Registration.php(72): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator()
#14 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Theme/Plugin/Registration.php(84): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration->register()
#15 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Plugin\Registration->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#18 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(159): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor))
#20 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#22 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#26 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#28 /home/u36619p31939/domains/orionyx.org/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#29 {main}
```

I'm going back up restore :)

**Edit**

Restoring the back-up has not done anything.
I have removed the created 'Vendor' folder, which ensures that I can log in again.

Comment: Just be sure that in theme.xml the copy paste don't brake the double quote `"` or quote `'`

Answer (score 0):

Also be sure that you didn't accidentally cut and paste magic quote characters. Look at all the double quotes and make sure they don't look angled. If they do, select them and type a double quote character over it.